# how to save an mp3 file on live website in ASP.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mp3, savefiledialog

I get the complete video data from youtube link which I then convert to MP3 format. All of this works on localhost but is not working on the when I put it on live.
**View:**

```
<form method="post" style="display:inline" action="@Url.Action("DownloadVideoFunc","Home",new {@link=item.Link})">
                    @Html.Hidden("returnURL", this.Request.RawUrl)
                    <button onclick="CallToastFunction();" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        Download MP3 too
                    </button>
                </form>
```

This is the controller function:

```
    var youTube = YouTube.Default; // starting point for YouTube actions
var video = youTube.GetVideo(link); // gets a Video object with info about the video
var path= Path.GetTempPath();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());//@"D:\"
var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = path + video.FullName };
var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{path + video.Title}.mp3" };
using (var engine = new Engine())
{
engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);
engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
}
System.IO.File.Delete(path + video.FullName);
```

It doesn't save the files and gives error. I can work with any JS function or C# function for getting the file to download.

Comment: `and gives error` - an error message usually contains a wealth of information - please share with us this nugget of information ... i.e. what is the error

Comment: On a server users do not normally have access to the file system of the server.  A client connecting to a server has only GUEST privileges.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/default-permissions-user-rights

Comment: the error message only shows to enable custome errors, nothing more

Comment: @jdweng  how do people download files through websites then?

Comment: By changing the permission in the IIS at top of article.  Or locating the file in a network drive that is accessible to clients.

Comment: can you guide me how to do this? @jdweng

Comment: Read the link above.